# Fixed size data types, C++, windows types

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get fixed sized floats and ints across all windows computers. As in, I have a program, I compile it and distribute the executable. I want the data types to be of constant bit size/ordering across all windows computers.

My first question is whether windows types defined at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx have fixed sizes across all windows computers (let's say running the same OS- Windows 7).

Basically, I'd like to transfer data contained in a struct over a network and I want to avoid having to put it all in a string or encode it into a portable binary form.

Edit: What about floats??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Floating Point

While there is no C++ standard defining the sizes for formats of floating point values [Microsoft has specified](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/36068) that they consistently use 4-byte and 8-byte IEEE floating point format for `float` and `double` types respectively.

### Integrals

As for integral types, Microsoft does have [compiler-specific defines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx) for fixed length variables. Some non-Microsoft compilers define fixed-size integral types using the `cstdint` header. *Neither* of these are based on official standards.

### Serialization

This will be terribly unportable and will most likely turn into a maintenance nightmare as your structs get more complicated. What you are effectively doing is defining an error-prone binary serialization format that must be complied with through convention. This problem has already been solved more effectively.

I would highly recommend using a serialization format like protocol buffers or maybe boost::serialization for communication between machines. If your data is hitting the wire, then the performance of serialization/deserialization is going to be an incredibly small fraction of transmission time.

### Alignment

Another serious issue that you'll have is how the struct is packed in memory. Your struct will most likely be laid-out in memory differently in a 32-bit process than it is in a 64-bit process.

In a 32-bit process, your struct members will be aligned on word boundaries, and on doubleword boundaries for 64-bit.

For example, this program outputs `20` on 32-bit and `24` on 64-bit platforms:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                             
#include <cstdint>

struct mystruct {
        uint32_t y;
        double z;
        uint8_t c;
        float v;
} mystruct_t;

int main() {
        std::cout << sizeof(mystruct_t);
}
```

Comment: I recognize the unportability. Time is a major concern however, deadlines to meet...
What you're saying is I can simply use float type and expect same size across all windows computers even running different hardware?

Comment: Windows today is x86, x86-64 or ARM. All have IEEE754 floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the types from

```
#include <cstdint>
```

Like `uint64_t`, `int16_t`, `int8_t` etc.

On the ordering: I'm pretty sure Windows only runs on Big-Endian hardware. Regardless, if platform portability is a concern, why don't you use a proper Serialization library and avoid nasty surprises?

- [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)
- [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) (Google's data interchange formatting library)

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is recent enough to give you the standard `<stdint.h>` header required by ISO C99 (or `<cstdint>` in recent C++), you'll better use it (and then, it would make your code portable, w.r.t. this particular issue, even on non Windows systems). So use types like `int32_t` or `int64_t` etc.

If serialization across several platforms is a concern, consider using portable binary formats like [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), [ASN1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN1), perhaps using the [s11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) library, or textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org) or [YAML](http://yaml.org)

Comment: Only helps with the size, not the ordering.

Comment: Also, note: question was tagged C++

Comment: Float numbers are very often IEEE754 today. And serialization formats or libraries deal with them.

Comment: Not only C++ but the OP was very specifically asking about Microsoft's support. Microsoft compilers do not provide `stdint.h`.